# Double Colon in WFS GetFeature Request Causes Issue

Tags: qgis, wfs, getfeature

When using QGIS 3.28.3 to query for a feature layer via a WFS GetFeature request, the request fails and the following in in the QGIS log:

*WFS exception report (code=none text=The value for parameter SRSNAME "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" is invalid: Value must be one of "urn:ogc:crs:EPSG:4326" or "EPSG:4326"). You may attempt reloading the layer with F5*

It appears that the server cannot handle the double colon in the request. I don't know anything about the server I've connected to.

Is there a preference setting in QGIS that I'm overlooking that can overcome overcome this issue?

Comment: double colon is correct form for urn without a version number.  See my answer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203355/whats-the-meaning-of-numbers-before-an-epsg-code-e-g-the-6-9-in-epsg6-94326/203466#203466

Comment: What version of WFS is being requested.  WFS 2.0 must accept urns but earlier WFS standards defined other patterns.  What does the GetCapabilities response for the server say it supports?

Comment: @nmtoken - The server says it accepts WFS 1.0.0 or WFS 1.1.0.  It does not accept WFS 2.0.  According to your other post, the optional authority definition should be between the two colons.  Is there any way around this in QGIS 3.28?

Comment: The authority is `EPSG`, the version number is missing, if there were a version number it would  be after the authority and before the CRS code like `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:10.091:4326`

Comment: To clarify, are you telling QGIS to open as 1.1.0 (or 1.0.0) , and the GetCapabilities response for that version doesn't report using URN's, but QGIS then requests them anyway?

Comment: The GetCapabilities response includes `<wfs:DefaultSRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326</wfs:DefaultSRS>` for each FeatureType (no double colon).  QGIS is sending `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:10.091::4326` (double colon).  So yes, I guess that is what I am saying.  Do you know of a workaround?  Is this an issue that needs reporting to QGIS?

Comment: It does sound like it may be a QGIS bug if that's the case.  You could try forcing WFS 1.0.0, because I think you are allowed only one CRS, so passing any SRS information is redundant.   For WFS 1.1.0 the spec (OGC 04-094) says that `Any valid URI value can be assigned to the srsName attribute` and it could be argued that the ogc urn is invalid because it's missing a colon.  It's odd that QGIS doesn't send one of the required forms of SRS identifier though, one of `EPSG:<EPSG code>` , `urn:EPSG:geographicCRC:<epsg code>` or `http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#<EPSG code>`